# angular.js Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] when injecting a factory

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm attempting to inject a factory called `recipesApp.recipeData` into my MainController, as soon as I added it, the app broke and I have been receiving the following error:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module recipesApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module recipesApp.recipeData due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'recipesApp.recipeData' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

My main app module is written as follows:

`var app = angular.module('recipesApp', ['ngRoute', 'recipesApp.recipeData']);`

My controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', 'recipeData', 
  function($scope,$http,$location,$rootScope,recipeData) {...}]);
```

My recipe factory:

```
angular
.module('recipesApp.recipeData', [])
.factory('recipeData', function($http) { 
    return { 
      getAllRecipes: function(){
        $http.get('/allrecipes'); 
      }
    };     
});
```

I have tried changing the file structure, the file naming convention. I have tried simply linking it onto the controller itself in the same file, I've changed the order in which it is being injected, and I've triple checked the spelling. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: You're confusing modules and services. There is no module named $http. $http is a service. A module depends on other modules, not on services. And you haven't posted the crusial information: your html file, which must have a script tag for all JS files of your app.

Comment: Oh my word, I knew it had to be a silly mistake. Forgot to include the script tag in my html file. Also, the http wasn't actually in my code. I was just typing it out too fast. I should have copied and pasted. Thank you!

Comment: @aadams22 If my answer helped solved your problem, you can always mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add `$http` as a module dependency, `$http` is a service, not a module. Remove it from your `recipesApp.recipeData` module dependencies

```
angular
.module('recipesApp.recipeData', [])
.factory('recipeData', function($http) { 
    return { 
      getAllRecipes: function(){
        $http.get('/allrecipes'); 
      }
    };     
});
```

Also make sure all the `.js` files are present in your `index.html`